# Creating an ArrayList of Subclass Objects

Tags: arraylist, subclass, superclass

I have a superclass `Appointment` that is then extended to a few different types of appointments. I need to make an ArrayList of appointments of different types which I did not think would be much of a problem since they all share a common superclass - `Appointment`. But when I try to add one of the subclasses `Daily` to the `ArrayList<Appointment> book = new ArrayList<Appointment>()` it fails to do so.

I have:

```
ArrayList<Appointment> book = new ArrayList<Appointment>()
```

Then later on in the program (I'm passing description, day, month, and year from the method it's place in):

```
book.add(new Daily(description, day, month, year));
```

And I get the suggestion of: The method add(AppointmentBook.Appointment) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Daily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from `ArrayList<Appointment>` to `ArrayList<? extends Appointment>`

Comment: Like `ArrayList<? extends Appointment> book = new ArrayList<? extends Appointment>()` ?

Comment: Yes, although you only need to declare the type once. `ArrayList<? extends Appointment> book = new ArrayList<>()`